# Parent process waiting on child process

Tags: unix

I was reading some articles regarding the wait() system call and I was trying to find like an idea of how the os implements it. I am trying to figure out how the parent process get notified. If the parent process is blocked on the system call how it is resumed? Will it be the child process that after it exits ask the scheduler to put back the parent process on running state so the system call can resume?

Comment: Could you link the articles?  Stack Overflow is about programming not kernel design therefore your question is borderline off-topic.  But, i believe, we can make the question better if we work together.  Anyhow, once a child dies the kernel must go through the parenting relationship before releasing the process' resources, this includes finding the parent process and sending it a signal `signal` (`SICHLD`).  There's a little more to it that deals with the `wait` system call itself.  But lets get the question right first.

Comment: Actually that was what I was looking, My doubt was in which way the parent process (that was already blocked) resumed. Now I see that it receives a signal. Like you said there are more things to do but I don't pretend that someone explains all the details. Like you said this is for programming not about kernel. But I appreciate your comment.

Comment: My only concern with signals is that I read here http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ipc/ipc.html in the part of IPC that signals were delivered every time a process exited from a system call which I didn't understand because if a process is blocked for example with the wait() system call it will not exit that function because is waiting. I know that I must be understanding something wrong.

Comment: I'll still argue that working on the question is a good idea since someone else might find it with a search.  I'd make an edit suggestion but i do not know what you did read.  Anyhow, process exit happens in kernel space (`exit()` is a system call too).  The kernel stores in its process descriptors whether a process is running or waiting (`TASK_RUNNING`, `TASK_STOPPED`), and it updates the parent's descriptor when a child exits.  Later, the process scheduler will reach the parent process, it will start running, leave the `wait()` call, and receive the signal.